# Expression for the gravitational-wave energy-momentum tensor without choosing a gauge

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, gravitational-waves, gauge-invariance, gauge

While studying section 7.6 of Carroll's introduction to general relativity, I encountered difficulties deriving equation 7.165 for the gravitational-wave energy-momentum tensor. Unfortunately, I was unable to derive the equation as presented in the book. Here's what I have done so far:

Using $t_{\mu \nu} = -\frac{1}{8\pi G} \{R^{(2)}_{\mu \nu}[h^{1}] -\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu \nu} \eta^{\rho \sigma}R^{(2)}_{\rho \sigma}[h^{1}]\}$

First I calculated the averaging brackets for $R^{(2)}[h^{1}]$:

$<R^{(2)}_{\mu \nu}[h^{1}]> = \ <\frac{1}{2} h^{\rho \sigma}\partial_\mu \partial_\nu h_{\rho \sigma} + \frac{1}{4}(\partial_\mu h_{\rho \sigma})(\partial_\nu h^{\rho \sigma}) + (\partial^\sigma h^\rho_{\ \ \nu})(\partial_{[\sigma}h_{\rho]\mu}) - h^{\rho \sigma}\partial_\rho\partial_{(\mu}h_{\nu)\sigma} + \frac{1}{2} \partial_\sigma(h^{\rho \sigma} \partial_\rho h_{\mu\nu}) - \frac{1}{4}(\partial_\rho h_{\mu\nu})\partial^\rho h - (\partial_\sigma h^{\rho \sigma} - \frac{1}{2}\partial^\rho h)\partial_{(\mu}h_{\nu) \rho}
>$

I managed, using $<\partial(AB)> = 0$, to

- Transform first and second terms in the first term of 7.165;
- Eliminate the fifth term;
- Annihilate fourth and seventh terms;
- Join together the sixty and second part the last term to produce minus two times the second term of 7.165(witch means $\frac{1}{4}(\partial_\mu h) (\partial_\nu h)$).

Resulting in:
$<R^{(2)}_{\mu \nu}[h^{1}]> = -\frac{1}{4}<(\partial_\mu h_{\rho\sigma})(\partial_\nu h^{\rho\sigma})> +\frac{1}{4}<(\partial_\mu h) (\partial_\nu h)> + \frac{1}{2}<(\partial^{\sigma} h^{\rho}_{\ \ \nu})(\partial_\sigma h_{\rho \mu})> - \frac{1}{2}<(\partial^{\sigma} h^{\rho}_{\ \ \nu})(\partial_\rho h_{\sigma \mu})> $

Because 7.165 doesn't have a $\eta_{\mu \nu}$ term, I believe that $<\eta^{\mu \nu}R^{(2)}_{\mu \nu}[h^{1}]>$ should be zero, so that in the end:

$t_{\mu \nu} = -\frac{1}{8\pi G}R^{(2)}_{\mu \nu}[h^{1}]$

But, first The result I got for $R^{(2)}_{\mu \nu}[h^{1}]$ is missing some parts of 7.165 and $<\eta^{\mu \nu}R^{(2)}_{\mu \nu}[h^{1}]>$ isn't zero either.

Any help is appreciated